# New job tax code

Tags: taxes, income-tax, united-kingdom

I had a summer internship last July (2022). And about to start a graduate job this coming September (2023). I need to choose which of the below statements best suits me. I've chosen the statement A when I was doing summer internship. And here are options I have:

Statement A - This is my first job since last April (in the United Kingdom) and I have not been receiving taxable Jobseeker's Allowance, Employment and Support Allowance or taxable Incapacity Benefit or a State or Occupational Pension.

Statement B - This is now my only job, but since last April I have had another job, or have received taxable Job Seeker's Allowance, Employment and Support Allowance or taxable Incapacity Benefit (in the United Kingdom). I do not receive a State or Occupational Pension (in the United Kingdom).

Statement C - As well as my new job, I have another job or receive a State or Occupational Pension.

Comment: Please check my edit has the years correct. When you say "I've chosen the statement A when I was doing summer internship" do you mean that for the internship in July 2022, you chose Statement A? Do you expect to receive any benefits in the tax year April 2023-April 2024?

Comment: So you're starting a new job in September 2023 and they've sent you the paperwork now for the job you won't start till September? And you won't be working or receiving any benefits between now and September?